# Getting Error on Readprocessememory on c#

Tags: c#

```
private static int FindPattern(byte[] Pattern)
        {
            Process[] P = Process.GetProcessesByName("example");
            if (P.Length == 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (modules == exmaple())
            {
                modules = P[0].MainModule.BaseAddress;
            }
            byte[] _Buffer = new byte[268435457];
            var tempVar = 0;
            ReadProcessMemory(P[0].Handle, modules, out _Buffer, _Buffer.Length, ref tempVar);


            int[] sBytes = new int[256];
            int Len = Pattern.Length - 1;
            var Dex = 0;

            for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                sBytes[i] = Pattern.Length;
            }

            for (int i = Len; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                sBytes[Pattern[i]] = Len;
            }

            while (Dex <= _Buffer.Length - Pattern.Length)
            {
                int i = Len;
                while (_Buffer[Dex + i] == Pattern[i])
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        return Dex;
                    }
                    i -= 1;
                }
                Dex += sBytes[_Buffer[Dex + Len]];
            }

            return -1;
        }
```

i tried a lot but i can't fix it.What did i did wrong?.
i am getting errors on this.Can anyone fix it for me please :

```
ReadProcessMemory(P[0].Handle, modules, out _Buffer, _Buffer.Length, ref tempVar);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ReadProcessMemory(P[0].Handle, modules, out _Buffer, _Buffer.Length, ref tempVar);   Error 1 The best overloaded method match for .findpattern.ReadProcessMemory(System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, byte[], uint, out uint)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\cx\Desktop\wr\findpattern.cs 46 4

Comment: That is not an error message.

Comment: Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.IntPtr'

Comment: So what is argument #2?

Comment: What's the value of `modules` if it is not "`exmaple()`"? And what type is it?

Comment: the documentation for ReadProcessMemory is using out parameter.have you checked it  out http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadProcessMemory.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ConsoleApplication81
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,[Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
        const int SIZE = 268435457;
        static void Main(string[] args)        
        {
            Process[] P = Process.GetProcessesByName("example");
            if (P.Length == 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (modules == exmaple())
            {
                modules = P[0].MainModule.BaseAddress;
            }
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SIZE);

            var tempVar = 0;
            ReadProcessMemory(P[0].Handle, modules, out buffer, SIZE, ref tempVar);

            byte[] _Buffer = new byte[SIZE];

            Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, _Buffer);


            int[] sBytes = new int[256];
            int Len = Pattern.Length - 1;
            var Dex = 0;

            for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                sBytes[i] = Pattern.Length;
            }

            for (int i = Len; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                sBytes[Pattern[i]] = Len;
            }

            while (Dex <= _Buffer.Length - Pattern.Length)
            {
                int i = Len;
                while (_Buffer[Dex + i] == Pattern[i])
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        return Dex;
                    }
                    i -= 1;
                }
                Dex += sBytes[_Buffer[Dex + Len]];
            }

            return -1;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ReadProcessMemory(P[0].Handle, modules, out _Buffer, _Buffer.Length, ref tempVar); if i change this to ReadProcessMemory(P[0].Handle, modules, out _Buffer, SIZE, ref tempVar); get only size error

Comment: Where do you get the size error?  Is it after the ReadProcessorMemory() method execute or some place else?  Try using Standard calling Convention :         [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] or CallingConvention.StdCall

Comment: Are you using the DllImport statement from pinvoke like I had in my code?  The DllImport and the call to ReadProcessorMemory() must have the same type parameters.